# Запасный или запасной?

Tags: фонетика

Почему в транспорте пишут "запасный", а не запасной, что более привычно?

Comment: @Статус, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Где-то встречается и запаснОй. Это равноправные варианты, но слово запа'сный по происхождению более древнее, чем запасно'й.

Подобная вариантность обусловлена исторически: различие в написании окончаний именительного падежа единственного числа -ый и -ой в соответствии с отсутствием или наличием ударения на окончании (добрый, красивый, но молодой, простой) восходит к различиям между старославянской и древнерусской формами прилагательных (старославянские прилагательные имели, независимо от ударения, только окончания -ый/-ий, древнерусские — только окончания -ой/-ей, а современная норма появилась в результате смешения этих традиций).  Сочетаемость слова запасный ограничена: на равных правах со своим современным вариантом запасной оно существует только в сочетании с существительными путь, полк и выход и некоторыми др.  В сочетаниях с другими словами прилагательное запасный квалифицируется как устаревшее.

Answer (score 1):

От Марины Королёвой (см. http://www.rg.ru/2014/08/14/koroleva.html ):

> Если в учреждении работают и рисуют на
> стенах указатели люди грамотные, то
> будет написано именно так и никак
> иначе - "запаснЫй выход". В противном
> случае может быть написано "запаснОй",
> но это уже, сами понимаете, - как
> повезет.
>
> Если же мы решим выяснить, какие рекомендации дают на этот счет
> словари, то уж тут придется запастись
> терпением, потому что вот словари-то
> дают как раз самые что ни на есть
> противоречивые указания. Начиная с
> классического Толкового словаря
> Владимира Даля, все они признают
> правильным - вы удивитесь - оба
> варианта, и запАсный, и слово
> запаснОй!
>
> Орфоэпический, часто используемый нами
> здесь словарь под редакцией Р.
> Аванесова, - тот так просто дает нам
> самую полную волю! Хотите - пишите
> запАсный выход, хотите - запаснОй.
> Хотите - запаснОй полк, хотите -
> запАсный. То же самое происходит и с
> путём (равно как и с "выходом", с
> которого мы начали): запАсный путь - и
> здесь, пожалуйста, запаснОй. Словарь
> ударений под редакцией И. Резниченко
> эти рекомендации всего лишь дословно
> дублирует, ничего дополнительно не
> разъясняя своим читателям.
>
> Пожалуй, самым строгим и
> принципиальным словарем остается
> Словарь ударений Ф. Агеенко и М.
> Зарвы, там имеет место хоть какая-то
> определенность. Вообще-то, замечает
> это справочное издание, правильным
> будет говорить "запаснОй": запаснАя
> деталь, запаснАя батарейка, запаснЫе
> части, "запасной вариант". А вот
> "выход" - тот самый, к которому
> приходится бежать вместе с человечком
> в чрезвычайных ситуациях, - "выход",
> он запАсный. Пояснений и этот словарь
> упорно не дает.
>
> Так что, на здоровье - называйте выход
> запАсным, как вам предписывает
> словарь, а все предметы, которые
> держите про запас, запаснЫми.
>
> Уверяю вас, на ошибку в этих случаях
> вам никто не укажет.

Comment: объяснение кроется в созвучном слове "опасный". запасный--безопасный.
вот и всех делов. нечего городить.